# What to do when there are conflicting answers and I still don't know the correct answer to a question?

Tags: discussion

I want to know the answer of an already posted question. I did this(following link) and supposedly I was wrong. What to do?

[What is the correct answer to this answered combinatorics problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496380/what-is-the-answer-actually)

Comment: First and foremost, you need to work on your question titles.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but this seems somewhat related: [Clarify an old answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/clarify-an-old-answer). Perhaps some of the questions linked there might be useful for you, too.

Comment: For what it's worth, it appears that the question you raised on main has been answered now, once in the comments, and once for real.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Just because there were three answers around (with two different outcomes) does not mean any one of them is correct. I have added a correct answer and commented the wrong ones, as this appeared a rather silly situation to me.

Comment: Just as defacing questions on the main site is a no-no, you should not deface your questions here on meta.

Comment: kill me now! duh!

Answer (score 7):

Given that you are not OP of the original question, but one of the providers of the two incompatible answers (which both turned out to be wrong), the proper thing to do would seem be: to scrutinise your answer, compare it to the other one, maybe add some explanation to your answer to make it clearer that your answer must be the right one (or find out why it isn't right in trying to do so; this often happens). Normally you will get the attention of OP just by providing or modifying your answer; in a desperate case you could add comments to ask whether your answer is considered correct by OP, and if not why not (I think you just have enough credit now to do that; probably you did not at the time though). Anyway, asking a separate question to the effect of "please tell me if my answer on that other question is correct" is not a proper thing to do.